# How to install cryptoloop module on Kali 4.6?

Tags: kali-linux, kernel-modules, disk-encryption

I am unable to launch the `cryptoloop` module on  Kali 4.6. **How can I to install it?**

```
# modprobe cryptoloop
modprobe: FATAL: Module cryptoloop not found in directory /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64
```

Comment: https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Encrypted_filesystems#Migrating_cryptoloop_volumes_to_dm-crypt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should re-compile the kernel to be able to load the `cryptoloop` module.

Edit your `source.list` , uncomment the `deb-src`, then run the following:

```
apt update 
apt-cache search linux-source
```

Then install the appropriate kernel source (the `linux-source-4.6.0` is an example):

```
apt install kernel-source-4.6.0
```

then

```
mkdir ~/kernel; cd ~/kernel
tar -xvf /usr/src/linux-source-4.6.0.tar.xz
cd linux-source-4.6.0
cp /boot/config-4.6.0-kali1-amd64 ~/kernel/linux-source-4.6.0/.config
```

To enable the `cryptoloop` support see : [Cryptoloop HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Cryptoloop-HOWTO/kernel-configuration.html)

Run ; `make menuconfig`

enable: `Device Drivers -> Block Devices -> Loopback device support`

Then compile the kernel.